# Eclipse can find file but Exe file cannot despite the fact that the file is in the same directory,

Tags: java, file, jar, exe

For my text maze game, `Eclipse` can find the text file and run it properly, but when I convert the `jar` of the project to an `exe`, the `exe` cannot find the file. Strange thing is that both the jar file I created and the `exe` are in the same directory, yet the `jar` file runs perfectly whereas the exe file does not. Why is this?

Here is my code:

```
try {
    //Find the file, create the maze, etc.
}
// Exceptions
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    File file = new File("maze.txt");

    System.out.println(file.canRead());
    System.out.println(file.getAbsoluteFile().exists());
}
```

Both of the two prints output false when I run the `exe`, even though all of the files are in the same directory and it works for the `Jar` file. Why is this? I am using `IExpress` to convert to an `exe` by the way.

Comment: Try [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @Madhan Thanks so much! The exe finally works. Please put down the answer so I could accept it.

Comment: have posted it You can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) as it is easy to use

Launch4j is a cross-platform tool for wrapping Java applications distributed as jars in lightweight Windows native executables. The executable can be configured to search for a certain JRE version or use a bundled one, and it's possible to set runtime options, like the initial/max heap size. The wrapper also provides better user experience through an application icon, a native pre-JRE splash screen, and a Java download page in case the appropriate JRE cannot be found.